# How to get rid of parentheses and theirs content in a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, split, qstring

I am trying to get rid of parentheses and the words contained in these parentheses in a QString. Could you please help me?

```
var1.at(0) = " MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ";

QStringList var2 = var1.at(0).split(QRegExp("\("), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

For this example, I am trying to get the function name which is only : `MainWindow`

I couldn't solve it with :

```
QRegExp("(");
QRegExp("\(");
QRegExp("\\(");
QRegExp("\((");
```

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do here? Not that string processing is rocket science, but it looks like your ultimate goal is to do something with the final string. What is it?

Comment: It is not final string, I am just asking how to add regexp with parentheses

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "split parentheses"? What is the result you expect from your example string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get function name you can use the following, if your function name is the first identifier in the string:

```
QString s("  MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ");
QRegExp e("(\\w+)");
if( e.indexIn(s) != -1 ) {
    qDebug() << e.cap(1); // MainWindow
}
```

If you want to get all until '(', you can use:

```
QString s("  MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : ");
QRegExp e("([^(]+)");
if( e.indexIn(s) != -1 ) {
    qDebug() << e.cap(1).trim();
}
```

Comment: @bolov: "I am trying to get function name which is MainWindow" (c) author

Comment: A solution that **doesn't** use regular expressions is likely easier to write, safer to use, and easier to read. It seems people are using regular expressions for everything, from tokenizing strings over waxing their cars to improving their sexual attractiveness. Regular expressions are a great tool for some problems. This is probably not one of those problems.